# STM32F101C8T6 Bootloader Application

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I have my application

bootloader appilication

```
    void bootloaderJumptoUserApplication(void)
{
    void (*bootloader_application_reset_handler)();
    printMessage("BL DEBUG MSG: Called bootloader_jump_to_user_application() \n");
    uint32_t mspValue = *(volatile uint32_t*) FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS;
    printMessage("BL DEBUG MSG: MSP Value: %#x \n", mspValue);
    __set_MSP(mspValue);
    uint32_t resetValue = *(volatile uint32_t*) (FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS + 4);
    printMessage("BL DEBUG MSG: Reset Value: %#x \n", resetValue);
    bootloader_application_reset_handler = (void*) resetValue;
    bootloader_application_reset_handler();
}
```

user application

```
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      printMessage("hello from the user application__huhuhuu\n");
      HAL_Delay(1000);
   }
```

system_stm32f1xx.c

```
#if defined(VECT_TAB_SRAM)
#define VECT_TAB_BASE_ADDRESS   SRAM_BASE       /*!< Vector Table base address field.
                                                     This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET         0x00000000U     /*!< Vector Table base offset field.
                                                     This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
#else
#define VECT_TAB_BASE_ADDRESS   FLASH_BASE      /*!< Vector Table base address field.
                                                     This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET         0x00008000U
```

but my bootloader does not jump to the user application

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: There are so many thigs that still need to be modified. Did you update the linker script to have the application to exist at an address after the bootloader?

Comment: where is the linker script?, what is the name of the file?

Comment: if it's STM32F101C8TX_FLASH.ld, yes i changed it

Comment: At which memory location did you store the user application? Are using openstm32 IDE for code development. Can you share your linker script where you made the change? Are you trying to develop a customer bootlooder. If so is the bootloader loaded at 0x0800_0000. Also how much flash is there in STM32F101C8T6 is it 64K Flash and 10 K RAM. Did you make changes to the flash base and vector table offset.